# Cron not working as expected

Tags: cron

I have an interesting problem with a cron job. I'm on a server with Cent OS and we're using Vixie cron. All this is very straighforward and i have a backup job that i want to run once every day at 01.00, so i created this simple crontab entry:

```
* 1 * * * /path/to/my/simpleJob.sh
```

What happens is this: at 01.00.02, the job runs as expected. Then cron (or something) continues to run the job every minute. Can anyone out there help me out? I have no idea what might be the root cause for this.

/M

Comment: Did you read `man 5 crontab`? What does the first asterisk stand for?

Answer (score 3):

The format is:

```
 +---------------- minute (0 - 59)
 |  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
 |  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
 |  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
 |  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
 |  |  |  |  |
 *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
```

So in your case being

```
* 1 * * * /path/to/my/simpleJob.sh
```

it means at hour 1, any minute.

To have it working *just* at 1.00, change it to:

```
0 1 * * * /path/to/my/simpleJob.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

The CronSandbox at [Dataphyx](http://dataphyx.com) lets you play about with the date/time values - you see a schedule of runtimes for whatever combination you put in.